# Install ubuntu-desktop nohup

Tags: software-installation

Is there any solution to install ubuntu desktop without choosing language
I want to use it on a sh bash script 
I have tried

```
apt-get install ubuntu-desktop --assume-yes
```

and

```
apt-get install ubuntu-desktop --force-yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` to `noninteractive`

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
apt-get -yq install ubuntu-desktop
```

`-q` for quiet output may not be necessary.  There is also a program called yes that will answer yes to any question.  Example: `yes|apt-get install [packagename]`

Comment: thanks, but Still give me keyboard configuration language